# How to connect a Field Node to a Group Input Node? Geometry Nodes Question

Tags: modifiers, objects, geometry-nodes

My question is quite basic: In Blender, you can connect certain sockets to the Group Input Node, which will then allow you to directly change the Geometry Node's settings (Since they are also Modifiers) on the Modifier Properties Tab.

Problem is: certain socket types aren't compatible with each other.

Any "pink node", or Field Nodes, for some reason cannot be connected to the Group Input node, as the image shows.

Am I missing something? I would just like to have a simple Value or Integer Node connected to my Group Input Node, so I can easily control the Geometry Node from the Modifier Properties tab.

Is there a way to connect both sliders in this way?
Or is there an alternative way?

I would be really glad if any of you could help me with this question, thank you[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just open the *N-Panel*, create a new input and set the type to *Integer*. If necessary, enter a value for *Default*, *Min* and *Max*.

Then connect the new *Group Input* to your Node and you can control the value via the *Modifier Panel*.

[image]

You must always connect the output of a node that provides a value with the input of a node that can accept a value.

The node `Integer` provides a value, just like the node `Group Input`, therefore the two sockets cannot be connected.

Comment: Oh I didn't know you could do that! Many thanks for the aid.